# I want to save PyQt5 settings when application close

Tags: python, pyqt5, qsettings

I want to save PyQt5 settings when application close. This is because the next time I run it again, it will run with the final settings. So, I wrote the code like this.

This is a main ui code.

```py
# main_ui.py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout
from sub_ui import SubUI


class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings = QSettings("A", "B")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        tabs = QTabWidget()
        tabs.addTab(SubUI(), "SubUI")

        vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vlayout.addWidget(tabs)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(vlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.setWindowTitle("MainUI")
        if self.settings.contains("geometry"):
            print("LOAD: " + str(self.settings.value("geometry")))
            self.setGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry"))
        else:
            self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 300)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("SAVE: " + str(self.settings.value("geometry")))
        self.settings.setValue("geometry", self.frameGeometry())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainUI()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

This is a sub ui code.

```py
# sub_ui.py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit


class SubUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings = QSettings("A", "B")
        self.label = QLabel("test")
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.init_ui()
        self.load_settings()

    def __del__(self):
        self.save_settings()

    def init_ui(self):
        hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(hlayout)

    def save_settings(self):
        self.settings.setValue("label", self.lineedit.text())

    def load_settings(self):
        if self.settings.contains("label"):
            self.lineedit.setText(self.settings.value("label"))
```

There is two problems.

#### 1. Changed **frameGeometry**

I ran this program and just close by clicked [X] icons. But the "self.frameGeometry()" value changes. Why this has happened?

=== More Information ===

I just ran the above program three times and turned it off by clicking the X.

```
LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1289, 370, 544, 604) 
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1289, 370, 544, 604) 

LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1288, 339, 546, 636) 
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1288, 339, 546, 636) 

LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1287, 308, 548, 668) 
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1287, 308, 548, 668)
```

The frameGeometry value changed by itself.

And this is an original problem of my program.

```
LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(852, 217, 1108, 1050)
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(851, 186, 1110, 1082)

LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(851, 186, 1110, 1082)
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(850, 155, 1112, 1114)

LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(850, 155, 1112, 1114)
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(849, 124, 1114, 1146)
```

===

How could I make frameGeometry value consistent?

#### 2. Can't save **sub_ui** settings.

When this program closes, it returns the error.

> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QSettings has been deleted

Therefore, I can't save the values.

How could I do what I want to do?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Ok, I will update it.

Comment: Ok, You could explain what you mean by *But the "self.frameGeometry()" value changes*, it's not very clear what you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't reproduce it on Linux. But you could use [`saveGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) and [`restoreGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry):

```py
class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings = QSettings("A", "B")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # ...
        self.setWindowTitle("MainUI")
        self.load_settings()
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def save_settings(self):
        self.settings.setValue("geometry", self.saveGeometry())

    def load_settings(self):
        if self.settings.contains("geometry"):
            self.restoreGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry"))
        else:
            self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 300)
```

2. In the __del__ method, the objects that depend on SubUI as the child widgets are already destroyed, which is indicated in the error message obtained by the OP.

   On the other hand only the `closeEvent()` method of the window (MainUI) since it is the only one that closes so that that the appropriate method to save all the data in QSettings implemented a generic method to save the data.

**main_ui.py**

```
class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings = QSettings("A", "B")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        for w in self.findChildren(QWidget) + [self]:
            if hasattr(w, "save_settings") and callable(w.save_settings):
                w.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def save_settings(self):
        self.settings.setValue("geometry", self.frameGeometry())
```

**sub_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit


class SubUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings = QSettings("A", "B")
        self.label = QLabel("test")
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.init_ui()
        self.load_settings()

    def init_ui(self):
        hlayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.lineedit)

    def save_settings(self):
        self.settings.setValue("label", self.lineedit.text())

    def load_settings(self):
        if self.settings.contains("label"):
            self.lineedit.setText(self.settings.value("label"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works well. :)

And this is the result of the first thing. I just ran it three times and turned it off by clicking the X.

LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1289, 370, 544, 604)
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1289, 370, 544, 604)

LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1288, 339, 546, 636)
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1288, 339, 546, 636)

LOAD: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1287, 308, 548, 668)
SAVE: PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(1287, 308, 548, 668)

The frameGeometry value changes itself.

Comment: Oops, I'll write it on my question.

Comment: @HoYa Edit your question and indicate in which part of the code you make your "print", also indicate the size of your screen.

Comment: @HoYa A question: Have you moved the window between the clicks to the "X" button ?, that is, let's say you close the window and return it open, I understand that when you close it you have not moved the window, am I correct?

Comment: @HoYa Also explain more about those 2 "prints" since your explanation is not clear at all.

Comment: Yes, I never moved the windows. And two cases have the same amount of moving. As you can see, the difference is always the same in any case. It is (1, 31, 2, 32).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I run on the windows. And sadly, it doesn't work. The error message like this. "TypeError: restoreGeometry(self, Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QRect'" I try to solve this, but I failed. I don't know how to convert from QRect to other things.

Comment: @HoYa You have to remove the previous file where the QSettings data was saved, to find its location use: `print(QSettings("A", "B").filename())`

Comment: You are awesome!!! I don't have the setting file. So I removed from the registry. And I think it works well. I've checked via this code. `print("LOAD: " + str(self.settings.value("geometry").toHex()))` and `print("SAVE: " + str(self.saveGeometry().toHex()))`